# How to place html tags inside javascript string?

Tags: javascript, html, string

I have this code right here:

```
generation.innerHTML=
"<!DOCTYPE html>\n"+
"<html>\n"+
 "<head>\n"+
  "<style>\n"+
   cinput+
  "\n<\/style>"+
 "\n<\/head>"+
 "<body>\n"+
  hinput+
  "\n<script>\n"+
   jinput+
  "\n<\/script>\n"+
 "<\/body>"+
"<\/html>";
```

But the doctype, html, head and body tags dissapear when I console log it, but when viewing it as a P element, all of the tags go away and leave the hinput, cinput, jinput variables.

How do I make all of it stay when viewing as a P element?

Comment: But... why? It seems like you are searching for a wrong solution to a problem.

Comment: @Rick It really isnt. I want to show the tags in a P element. I know what I'm asking for.

Comment: @Vairoon — By "show tags" do you mean "Display the text `<html>` to the reader" and not "Treat `<html>` as the start tag for an HTML element"

Comment: @Quentin yes, and all the other tags and closing tags too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` tries to parse the data as HTML. Hence the name.

If you want to treat it as plain text, [use `textContent` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Comment: but now the \n doesnt create a new line, how would I create a new line now?

Comment: `<br>`, `<pre>`, `white-space`, the usual.